# Not able to run source facebookenv/bin/activate

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x

I'm trying to install Facebook SDK for Python from here
https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-from-git 
Here's the full code

```
 virtualenv facebookenv
source facebookenv/bin/activate
pip install -e git+https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk.git#egg=facebook-sdk
```

The `virtualenv facebookenv` and `pip install -e git+https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk.git#egg=facebook-sdk` works well in the Windows Command Prompt but not `source facebookenv/bin/activate`. When I try to run it returns tha source is not recognized command.

Comment: What is your shell ? Please add the ouput of the ``source`` command to your question

Comment: @loutre *"not recognized command"*

Comment: I didn't read you were using Windows. See the question you've duplicated.